# ghostscript not creating exact images

Tags: thumbnails, ghostscript

I am running below script to create images from postscript file, the images are coming but on first page watermark is not there.

gs -dUseCIEColor -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -dFirstPage="1" -dLastPage=2 -sOutputFile=outputImage_%0d_A.gif  -dJPEGQ=100 -r300 -q inputFile.ps -c quit;'

I am giving the link of ps file which i am using.

http://speedy.sh/Y7vWj/inputFile.ps

Can anybody please help!!!!

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

OK you haven't stated what version of Ghostscript you are using, nor have you been very clear about what is missing. By 'watermak' do you mean the dark grey text 'PAULDAVIS' written diagonally across the very dark grey rectangle ?

If so then I can see that using the current version of Ghostscript and your command line, its not missing

A few observations on your command line:

-dUseCIEColor - Don't use this unless you know **exactly** what you are doing and why you want this, I'm guessing you don't (because you have not set any Color Rendering Dictionary). With this you get very dark grey text which is nearly invisible against the very dark grey rectangle. Not surprising since this relates to colour management.

You've set the device to jpeg, but you've set the output file to have a .gif extension.

You are using -dFirstPage and -dLastPage which have no effect when the input is not PDF (though this is added as a new feature in unreleased code).

You've set FirstPage=1 and LastPage=2 on a 2 page file.....

You have set -dFirstPage="1", which isn't going to work for any code which parses and uses it. The quotes won't work.

I'd recommend you do **not** set -q or -dQUIET when trying to diagnose problems, telling Ghostscript to be quiet will potentially mean you miss useful information.

-c quit; -c means 'process the next part of the command line as PostScript'. But quit; isn't valid PostScript (the semicolon should not be present) and will throw a PostScript error. If you want GS to exit after processing, consider simply using -dBATCH.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply...   I am using Ghostscript 8.70 and yes you are right the diagonal line written as Paul Davis is missing...

Comment: Well the first thing to do is try a version which is less than 6 years old. The current version is 9.16 and 9.18 will be released shortly. Secondly, as I said, unless you have a very good reason for using it, do not set -dUSECIEColor. If you care about colour, and know **precisely** what you are doing, you can use this flag to control the colour management. If you aren't absolutely certain you know why you are doing this, then don't, the results will be much better without it.